# Freshdesk API (ticket forwarding) returns 400 for "Unexpected/invalid field in request"

Tags: freshdesk, thunderclient

I am attempting to create a method to forward a Freshdesk ticket to a specified email address along with an added message. The method and API call work fine, until I add the `user_id` property to the body of the API call, and then it fails with a 400 status and the message:

> "Unexpected/invalid field in request"

This is unexpected because [the Freshdesk API Documentation](https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#forward_tickets) lists `user_id` as a valid field. What am I doing wrong?

The following data has been anonymized, but the anonymized portions are definitely correct.

Here is the response I am getting:

```
{
  "description": "Validation failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": "user_id",
      "message": "Unexpected/invalid field in request",
      "code": "invalid_field"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the URI I am using:

`POST https://{mydomain}.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets/118730/forward`

My Headers:

```
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Thunder Client (https://www.thunderclient.com)
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic {verified key}=:X
```

And the body of the request:

```
{
  "body": "<p>The workflows for this ticket have been completed: '{workflowNumber}'</p><br><br>",
  "user_id": "2043094848729",
  "to_emails": ["{me}@{mycompany}.com"]
}
```

I should also note that this works perfectly when I remove the `user_id` from the body of the request, but it fails when `user_id` is included, regardless of whether it is in string or int format.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by using the "agent_id" parameter instead of "user_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the `agent_id` parameter instead of `user_id`.